# how to center text html css

Tags: html, css

i want to make the text "TITLE" in this html and css code,

```css
#headerf {
  background-color: #717571;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.headert {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  top: 0px;
}
.headert h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.headert a.h-left {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.headert a.h-right {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerf" class="headert">
  <a href="#" class="h-left">LEFT</a>
  <h3>TITLE</h3>
  <a href="#" class="h-right">RIGHT</a>
</div>
```

or this http://jsfiddle.net/didinz/6vp34frd/

i have done everything i know but it still doesnt work(and become worse)
and i'm stuck
Thanks in advance guys ^_^

Comment: well... if you don't want to be bothered about this. There are a lot of css framework around to help you to do layouting without have to write your own css, eg: bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid or 960 grid system http://960.gs/ and many other

Comment: thanks @emmauel it's help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#headerf {
  background-color: #717571;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  text-align: center;
}
.headert {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  top: 0px;
}
.headert h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.headert a.h-left {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.headert a.h-right {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: block;
}

h3 {text-align: center; display: block; width: 90%; margin: auto; left: 5%; position: absolute; top: 5px;}
```

```html
<div id="headerf" class="headert">
  <h3>TITLE</h3>
  <a href="#" class="h-left">LEFT</a>
  <a href="#" class="h-right">RIGHT</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way:

```
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5%;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
#headerf {
  background-color: #717571;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.headert {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  top: 0px;
}
.headert h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.headert a.h-left {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.headert a.h-right {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: block;
}

h3 {text-align: center; display: block; width: 90%; margin: auto; left: 5%; position: absolute; top: 5px;}
```

```html
<div id="headerf" class="headert">
  <h3>TITLE</h3>
  <a href="#" class="h-left">LEFT</a>
  <a href="#" class="h-right">RIGHT</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is one line of text and/or image, then it is easy to do. Just use:

```
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 90px;       /* the same as your div height */
```

that's it. If it can be multiple lines, then it is somewhat more complicated. But there are solutions on http://pmob.co.uk/ Look for "vertical align".

Since they tend to be hacks or adding complicated divs... I usually use a table with a single cell to do it... to make it as simple as possible.